# What's the best position for the global navigation of an application within an intranet site that has its own global navigation?

Tags: navigation, metro, intranet

I'm designing an interface for an application that is most likely going to sit within our intranet. Users will access it from our intranet and we feel that it will make their jobs easier if they have the intranet global navigation available so they can navigate to other areas in the intranet to continue their work.

However we're not sure if the positioning of the global navigation for the application conflicts with the global nav of the intranet. Here is a mockup of the design:

[image: Mockup of design]

As you can see, there is a local navigation within the application. There are a few pages that have this local navigation that lets users browse content local to the context.

This app will set a precedent for future apps as we are trying to create a standard look & feel. 
Our app design follows the windows 8 UI guidelines & the menu at the top emulates the xbox interface behaviour.

My question is 
**does this violate any UI/UX principles due to it's position, does it conflict with the intranet global nav, why/why not?, and if you feel that it does, do you have any other recommendations?**

Please remember that there are two levels of navigation that need to be accommodated for within the application (global+local).

**Update: Here is an image of the application with the intranet nav + its own nav**
It's not the final design, but this should illustrate how it will look and the difference in appearance between the global intranet nav and the application global nav.

[image: Application graphic design]

Comment: I don't want to flag this as duplicate, because the other question only has the one unaccepted answer, but may be relevant: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14298/global-navigation-best-practices

Comment: It's not really relevant as this global nav doesn't 'tie together' separate sites that look completely different. Also it doesn't address this specific question

Answer (score 3):

There is a violation of consistency I think.  There are controls with the same names( e.g. Home) that take users to different places in the ui and outcomes of controls (e.g. Search) are different. I am wondering if just showing one control (e.g < Organization x) to get back to the global app could work in your situation. If you are going to show another app inside intranet there would need to be very clear visual distinction to show the app's "scope/boundaries" so it is clear to the user that all controls only apply to the app.

Comment: Yeah it is a very clear visual distinction, I might upload a pic to demonstrate the difference. Also i think it's clear that the home and home buttons take you to different places due to the visual distinction, though I may be wrong.

Comment: Re: duplicate home buttons -- consider a different label for the app home link like "Application Start" or "Step 1". Where Home links are used they are usually global to the site. Visually setting your application apart from its container will help too.